# About a metric's symmetric properties...

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetric-matrices, general-relativity

Hello fellow mathematicians!

I was wondering why most metrics I have seen in Relativity are symmetric, also a property I have started to notice in my differential geometry book.

I guess the definition through the "dot-product" may be the reason why...

$$ g_{\alpha \beta}=\vec{x}_\alpha\cdot \vec{x}_\beta  $$

But:

- Are there non-symmetric metrics?
- What can be said about them?
- Also, how do we call those metrics which only have non-zero components in the main diagonal?
- And perhaps the question that has been bothering me a lot: **What can be said about a metric having non-zero components out off the main diagonal?**

I have been having thoughts on physical implications but since I'm not that far into Relativity nor Diff. Geometry, I can't really come up with something yet.

My main book has been Kreysizg's Differential Geometry, which may not be suited for some questions I have been thinking off, yet it has been an awesome book to start with! Any further recommendations?

Comment: Most metrics are symmetric? Which ones aren't? In geometry, it's either symmetric or totally skew-symmetric objects that are going to show up. You can always symmetrize the matrix to get a dot product that *is* symmetric. The point is that positive-definiteness is usually defined only for symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually want a metric to "measure" distance in some way.  One property we want to be preserved is that the distance from A to B is the same as the distance from B to A.  This property is exactly what symmetry in the form means.  So if a metric is not symmetric then it doesn't really do anything useful.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right. While metrics can be used to acquire a notion of distance, the input to a metric is not two points $A$ and $B$ between which the metric is computing a distance. The inputs to a metric are tangent vectors, so that a similar statement to yours that one can make is: the symmetry of the metric encodes that the *angle* between tangent vectors $u$ and $w$ is the same as that between $w$ and $u$.